# Vimscript: how to overwrite a variable that is inside an if block?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, functions, variables

I have some code in a function like so:

```
  let branch = substitute(system('git rev-list -1 HEAD'), '\n', '', 'g')
  let num_branches = system('echo `git branch --contains '.branch.'` | wc -l')
  if num_branches == 1
    branch = system('git branch --contains '.branch.' | cut -c3-') 
  endif
```

But `branch` is not overridden like I would expect. How do I reassign `branch`?

Comment: you should rather explain what exactly you are trying to achieve here. Note: backticks are most likely wrong here.

Comment: I'm trying to get the current git commit, and get the name of the branch associated with it if there is only one.

Comment: so have you tried: `system('git branch --contains ' .. branch .. ' | wc -l')` ?

Comment: Reassigning is done with `let` in vimscript prior to `vim9script`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt yes I tried `system('git branch --contains ' .. branch .. ' | wc -l') ` and it goes inside the `if` block. Will try `let`.

Answer (score 2):

The `system()` return includes a trailing newline:

```
:let ls = system('ls | wc -l')
:echo '|' .. ls .. '|'
|61
|
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

You can use `->trim()` to remove newlines. Also, the command is needlessly complex: `git branch` already outputs text, so no need for `echo` and backticks here.

You're also missing a `let` inside the `if` check; you always need to use `let` to assign variables.

It's generally a good idea to use `shellescape()` on variables you use inside `system()`, so it works when variables contain special shell characters. I prefer to use `printf()` for this, but you can use string concatenation with `..` too.

Putting it all together:

```
let branch       = system('git rev-list -1 HEAD')->trim()
let num_branches = system(printf('git branch --contains %s | wc -l', branch->shellescape())->trim()
if num_branches == 1
    let branch = system(printf('git branch --contains %s | cut -c3-', branch->shellescape()))->trim()
endif
```